# How to print values inside a loop in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

This question might seem to be a possible duplicate of [How to print values in the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610765/postgres-how-to-print-values-in-the-loop). Even though the particular link contains a good solution it, doesn't seems to work for me. This is the core part of the stored procedure that I've written.

```
BEGIN 
FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'i is %',i;
END LOOP;
RETURN; 
END;
```

While executing the procedure I'm always getting the result as

> No rows found.
>
> Total runtime: 1.787 ms
>
> SQL executed.

Can someone tell me how to print the value of `i`? The postgresql version that I'm using is `8.4`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the real code, not something else. Using DO, this example works perfectly (version9.4)

Comment: This is the code. What else do you need? Please clarify. I've very well explained in my question that I'm using postgresql version 8.4. So a working code in the upgraded version doesn't seems to be helpful to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks well. There are few possibilities:

- your client doesn't show asynchronous messages correctly
- you have higher `client_min_messages` than `notice`- can be changed by command:

  ```
  SET client_min_messages TO notice;
  ```
- you are looking to wrong window - Server messages are shown in other window than result usually. In pgAdmin, you have to choose a tab `Messages`

Comment: Pavel, Thank you so much. It is showing up in the messages tab in the pgAdmin.